# How to avoid "KERN_WARNING" messages from console during boot time

Tags: boot, kernel, console, loglevel

There are several kernel messages printed to the console during boot time. I do not want the messages with loglevel "KERN_WARNING" to printed to the console. I only want the loglevels above "KERN_WARNING" like "KERN_ERR" to be printed to the console during boot time. When and where should i make changes to get this done. Do the changes have to be made during build time of kernel? Where should i make the changes to change the loglevel.?

I am using WindRiver Linux on PowerPC in an embedded environment. The boot loader i am using is uboot.

When i do `ps -eaf`, i **cannot** find the `klogd` daemon as well.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file /etc/sysctl.conf

Uncomment the line  `kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7`